# HTML/CSS: How to have a container's scrollbar control the scroll of an inner-inner div?

Tags: css, html, scroll, overflow

[It wasn't easy to decide how to phrase the question...]

Here's an [example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dgYXz/).

The purple div (`'#inner'`) is 1000px high.

How can I make the scrollbar of the **red** div (`'#out'`) - 
control the scrolling of the **purple** div (`'#inner'`)?

Or create a seemingly similiar effect visual-wise, 
 I feel like there's a trivial solution here that i'm missing... :\

Comment: I think this can only be done with JavaScript using the `onscroll` event.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this jquery plugin: http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/
and make the blue scroll follow the red scroll.

```
var top = $(redBox).scrollTop();
var left = $(redBox).scrollLeft();
$(blueBox).scrollTo( { top:top, left:left}, 800 );
```

This is assuming I understand your question.